# Gate-source connected MOSFETs for voltage division

Tags: voltage-divider, ldo, nmos, power-management, thermal-cutoff

Currently, I am engaged in the design of a Thermal Shutdown circuit for an LDO regulator. In this endeavor, I have obtained a circuit schematic from a senior colleague, which utilizes three NMOS transistors configured as voltage dividers.

This particular arrangement is employed due to the minimal current flow observed across the branch, which is on the order of picoamperes.

I have provided an attached image of the schematic for reference. Subsequently, I conducted simulations and confirmed the circuit's satisfactory performance.

However, I am now seeking a mathematical approach to determine the aspect ratio of the transistors and the resulting resistance offered by the MOSFETs, as they operate in cut-off mode.

Unfortunately, I have been unable to locate a suitable formula that elucidates the resistance of a MOSFET in cut-off or subthreshold conditions, including the role of non-zero body-source voltage of the upper two MOSFETs.

Can we approximate the resistance of the individual NMOS transistors using the current equation of subthreshold?[image: Voltage Divider created by gate-source connected NMOS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having pA current in a voltage divider branch is very risky. The reason is that the voltage is actually getting set by the diode leakage currents. The accuracy of the voltage divider output depends on how well the leakages are matched and this cannot be predicted because this is not modelled.

Coming to your question of how to determine the resistance, I'd recommend to just use the simulation using the models.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my doubts. However, what do you mean by "leakages are matched"

Comment: What I mean is just like the threshold voltages of MOSFETs have a mismatch from device to device, diode leakage currents can also vary from device to device. For example, in nominal corner, if you get the voltage divider output to 0.5V in your simulation, in reality, on Silicon, there will be a variation around 0.5V but, we have no way to estimate how much that variation will be.